# Auto- ignition on stove

Tags: stove

I recently brought a new stove, with auto-electric ignition. It works well, except for the fact that whenever I turn any knob(it's a 3-burner) ,the sparkers on ALL the burners go off. I don't know if that's by design or not, so if anyone can comment on this, that would be really helpful.

Comment: FWIW, that's the case with the last two cooktops I've lived with. (One really old and one really new.) It seems like it would make for simpler electronics.

Comment: Utterly normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This is typical for spark-ignition cooktops

Electronic (spark) ignited cooktops generally run all the igniters when any burner is engaged in the ignition position.  This is done for both simplicity (easier to have one ignition module feeding HV to four sets of electrodes than to have an ignition module per burner or to switch the high ignition voltage on/off) and safety (to limit the size of the FWOOSH that a failed igniter could otherwise give you).

Comment: Looking for "FWOOSH"  in the dictionary, didn't find it. :-)